# PHP unzip with password, unpacking despite wrong password

Tags: php, cryptography, zip

I am having an issue whilst using phps ZipArchive.

Using the example from the docs http://php.net/manual/en/ziparchive.setpassword.php#115803 I have found that the zip will extract on a (at the moment specific string) that isn't the password, giving me the contents but they are corrupt.

The zip I am testing with has a single text file and the archive has a password of "uwotm8" but the code accepts "ccccca" as a password and gives me the file (albeit with corrupt text) but fails on everything else.

Why is this? Is this an issue with php? Is there an accurate way of giving the zip a password and checking if it opens?

Thanks

Update: I am on PHP 7.0.10 on Windows 10 (via wamp)

Comment: Can you clarify *"gives me the file but fails on everything else"*…?

Comment: Which PHP version are you using? 5.6 has an issue whereby it would extract empty files (or overwrite existing files) when an incorrect password is supplied, but I'm not aware of a situation where it would extract corrupted files. See https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=70752

Comment: @iainn PHP 7.0.10 on Windows 10 (via wamp). Will update question to include this

Comment: @deceze i have got a array of random passwords for testing, gives me the file with a body size with the "ccccca" password, but the text in the file is corrupt/garbage data. The code acts that it has successfully unpacked it using that pw, and fails on all the others.

Comment: I'm still not sure what "fails on all the others" means… "other" what? Anyway… to some degree it's intentional that the wrong password isn't rejected, but simply results in garbage. Encryption to some degree is just XORing bytes with random noise. If you XOR them again with the same noise, you get the original back. XOR them with something else, you get random noise back. This makes it *harder* to attack encrypted data, since there's no obvious indicator what the right answer is.

Comment: @OnIIcE Looks like the bug I mentioned was actually only fixed in 7.0.12, although it's still only related to producing blank files rather than corrupted ones. Might be worth trying an upgrade

Comment: @deceze the code `$zip->extractTo(__DIR__)` returns false on known incorrect passwords, which "ccccca" is one of. However setting the password to  "ccccca" via `$zip->setPassword("ccccca")` and running the extract line, results in a positive return value and files with corrupted data in. The other incorrect passwords all return the correct "false" response from `$zip->extractTo(__DIR__)` after the password is set by `setPassword` and the attempted unpacking leaves the 0 byte files that @iainn is talking about with the PHP bug.

Comment: @iainn just upgraded to 7.0.12 and no change =( thanks though!